# TypeScript Error TS2339, but the properties do exist

Tags: typescript2.0

When I compile the following TypeScript code using gulp I get: error TS2339: Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'Response'. The ErrorList window in Visual Studio 2015 reports the same error for `data.accessToken` and `data.expiryDate`. When I comment out the two lines which reference the variable `data`, the code runs and the debugger shows that `data` is not of type 'Response' and does in fact contain the properties `data.accessToken` and `data.expiryDate`. In Visual Studio, when I hover the mouse over the `data` variable, the tooltip correctly reports that the type of `data` is `any`.

Why is TypeScript failing to transpile this correctly and how do I solve the problem? Why does TypeScript think `data` is of type `Response` and not of type `any`?
I am using TypeScript 2.1.4. http.fetch is using the aurelia fetch client [documented here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/2)

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
import 'fetch';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {BearerToken} from './common/bearer-token';
export class ApiToken
{
...
    public refreshToken(): Promise<BearerToken>
    {
        let token: BearerToken = new BearerToken();
        token.accessToken = "no_data";
        token.expiryDate = Date.now();

        return this.http.fetch('/Account/getToken')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>
            {                
                console.log('ApiToken.refreshToken returned data: ' + data);

                // The next two lines cause build errors. 
                // When commented out the code runs and the debugger shows that
                // data.accessToken and data.expiryDate do exist on data.
                token.accessToken = data.accessToken;
                token.expiryDate = data.expiryDate;           

                return token;
            })
            .then((t) => { return this.saveToken(t) });
    }
...
}
```

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "./typings/index.d.ts",
    "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts",
    "./jspm_packages/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jspm_packages",
    "dist",
    "build",
    "test"

  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

I tried specifying the type of `data` with the following but it did not fix the problem, though the error message was different, both shown below:

```
interface TokenResult
{
    accessToken: string;
    expiryDate: string;
}    

....

public refreshToken(): Promise<BearerToken>
{
    let token: BearerToken = new BearerToken();
    token.accessToken = "no_data";
    token.expiryDate = new Date(Date.now().toString());

    return this.http.fetch('/Account/getToken')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data: TokenResult) =>
        {                
            console.log('ApiToken.refreshToken returned data: ' + data);

            token.accessToken = data.accessToken;
            token.expiryDate = new Date(data.expiryDate); 

            return token;
        })
        .then((t) => { return this.saveToken(t) });
}
```

And the error was:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(data: TokenResult) => BearerToken' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response) => BearerToken | PromiseLike<BearerToken>'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'TokenResult'.
      Property 'accessToken' is missing in type 'Response'.
```

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer to this from a contributor on gitter. A cast to `any` and then a cast to `TokenResult`did the trick, as follows...

```
return this.http.fetch('/Account/getToken')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data: any) =>
    {
        console.log('ApiToken.refreshToken returned data: ' + data);

        token.accessToken = (<TokenResult>data).accessToken;
        token.expiryDate = (<TokenResult>data).expiryDate;

        return token;
    })
    .then((t) => { return this.saveToken(t) });
```

Comment: had the same problem. declaring (data: any) did the trick for us. a further cast was not necessary in our case